# De onde vem a palavra "rolê" e como ela começou a ser utilizada?

Tags: etimologia, português-brasileiro, uso-de-palavras, origem-histórica, informalidade

[*Rolé* (Michaelis)](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/palavra/m8mxq/rol%C3%A9/) é uma palavra que é frequentemente usada em algumas regiões, e eu gostaria de saber qual sua origem e a história de sua utilização.

Examplos:

> Fui dar um rolê na casa de um amigo ontem.
>
> Vamos dar um rolê amanhã?
>
> Tô afim de dar um rolê hoje.

Comment: https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/rol%C3%AA

Comment: Origem obscura. Provavelmente não relacionado, porém o conceito 'rolê' da capoeira tem o mesmo nome.

Comment: Você se refere a "rolê" mesmo, ou "rolé"?

Comment: Por favor acrescente a qual dos significados de "rolê" (ou "rolé", se for o caso) você se refere.

Comment: Acrescentei alguns exemplos.

Comment: Rolé é dar uma volta, um passeio. Rolê é capoeira. Tá lá direitinho para o Brasil e Portugal no Priberam, uma ótima ferramenta. O verbete até diz que rolé pode vir do francês, rouler, rodar.

Comment: Sim, é possível achar várias definições para praticamente qualquer palavra, esperava que alguém pudesse me dar alguma coisa mais concisa, e amarrada ao invés de pegar um link e o definir como verdade única.

Comment: @Centaurus, é que o Felipe é de São Paulo. Parece que lá o *rolé* é *rolê*. Aliás, seja bife, seja gola, seja passeio (à exceção do rolê da capoeira, que eu não consegui documentar), já se escreveu *rolé* e *rolê*.

Comment: @Jacinto  valeu.      https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valeu

Comment: @Centaurus, lol, mas tu pensavas que eu não conhecia esse "valeu"?! :)

Comment: @Jacinto  Imaginei que não.  É de uso restrito a adolescentes e adultos jovens. E não acredito que tenha cruzado o Atlântico.  :-)

Comment: @Centaurus, há muitos brasileiros deste lado também.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os dicionários dizem apenas que ***rolé*** e ***rolê*** vêm do francês *roulé*  ([Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/rol%C3%A9) e [Michaelis)](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/rol%C3%A9/), ou que *rolé* ‘passeio’ é de origem obscura, vindo possivelmente de *rolê* ‘bife enrolado’ e ‘movimento de capoeira’, vindo este também do francês *roulé* (Houaiss, Lisboa, 2002, [Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/rol%C3%A9). [*Rouler* (Larousse)](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/roul%C3%A9/70049?q=roul%C3%A9#69288) é o particípio passado de [*rouler* (Larousse)](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/rouler/70055?q=rouler#69294), que significa ‘rolar, rodar, enrolar’. Então fiz uma busca na [Hemeroteca Digital Brasileira](http://bndigital.bn.gov.br/hemeroteca-digital/) para ver os usos ao longo do tempo. Eis os resultados:

- Um rolê pode ser um ***bife rolê***, ‘bife enrolado’. Esta é a aceção que eu encontrei mais cedo, logo a partir de 1952 no periódico carioca [Última Hora](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=386030&pesq=bife%20rol%C3%AA&pasta=ano%20195). Nos anos 50 e 60 escrevia-se predominantemente *rolé*. Os dicionários concordam que vem do francês *roulé*.
- Também há a [***gola rolê*** (Priberam)](https://dicionario.priberam.org/rol%C3%A9), que é uma gola enrolada ou no mínimo dobrada. Encontrei-a com frequência a partir de 1962, começando com este artigo em [*A Cigarra* (São Paulo).](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=003085&pesq=gola%20rol%C3%AA&pasta=ano%20196) Encontra-se nos anos 60 algumas vezes escrito *rolé*.
- *Rolê* é também um **movimento de capoeira**. Consiste em o capoeirista rolar o corpo em torno de um braço apoiado no chão. Não consegui encontrar esta aceção na Hemeroteca. Possivelmente está lá: “bife rolê” ou “dar rolê” encontram-se facilmente, mas quando se procura só “rolê” o buscador retorna centenas de resultados, mas todos os que vi são erros de reconhecimento, como o segmento *role* de *controle* e coisas assim. No Google Books só encontrei a partir dos anos 90.
- E finalmente, ***dar um rolé*** ou ***rolê*** significa também ‘**dar um passeio, volta**’. Encontrei este uso primeiro num jornal carioca de 1961, e depois com crescente frequência a partir dos anos 70. O artigo de 1961 é bastante revelador e sugere que o termo era então gíria restrita a certos grupos, incluindo marginais. Cito então uma boa parte (negrito meu em todas as citações):

  > Madrugada de domingo. A chamada “ZBM” (zona do baixo meretrício) começa a se esvaziar. Dois homens, o “margina” (marginal) e seu “agá” (comparsa) entram no Bar “Chave de Ouro”. Dirigem-se ao garção:
  >   —**A “pesada” já deu um “rolé”?**
  >   —“Barra mansa”—responde o interpelado que é também um iniciado na “giriologia”.
  >   Satisfeitos e tranquilizados, o “margina” e seu “agá” sentam-se a uma mesa. Sabem que a “barra é mansa” (tudo calmo) porque a “pesada” (policiais da Delegacia de Vigilância) não passou por ali fazendo **ronda (“rolé”)**.
  >   [“Giriologia”, *Última Hora*, Rio de Janeiro,  13 de novembro de 1961, p. 8.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=386030&pesq=deu%20rol%C3%A9&pasta=ano%20196)

A partir dos anos 70, o este uso já era mais alargado, mas há indicações de que continuava a ser gíria apenas de certos grupos. Mais sobre isso abaixo.

### Origem de *rolé/rolê*

O que me intriga é como é que expressões tão da cultura popular brasileira—*dar um rolé/rolê* e o *rolê* da capoeira—foram buscar uma palavra ao francês. Uma hipótese que me parece plausível é que o *roulé/rolê* tenha vindo para o Brasil por via culinária. O *bife rolê* parece ser o uso mais antigo de todos os *rolês*, e é sabida a influência do francês na terminologia culinária:  *flambê*  vem do francês *flambé* [(Michaelis)](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/flamb%C3%AA/), *suflê*, de *soufflé* [(idem)](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/sufl%C3%AA/), etc. Aliás, o *bife rolé* do [artigo de 1952](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=386030&pesq=bife%20rol%C3%AA&pasta=ano%20195) vinha acompanhado de “soufflé” e “petit-pois”.

Então, *rolê/rolé* poderia ter começado por ser usado na culinária e depois ter sido adotado para descrever o movimento rolante do capoeirista e um passeio curto. Note-se que a relação semântica entre *rolar* e *dar um rolé* existe também com outras palavras: temos *girar*, e *dar um giro* também significa ‘dar um passeio’ [(Aulete 2)](http://www.aulete.com.br/giro); e temo *votar* e *voltar-se*, e *dar uma volta* também significa ‘dar um passeio’.

### Evolução de *dar um rolé*

Como o foco da pergunta é em *dar um rolé*, dou mais uns pormenores sobre a evolução da expressão. Mostro na tabela abaixo a evolução da frequência da expressão. Até à década de 90, discrimino as diferentes grafias e sentidos; depois apresento só o total, que discriminar exige um tempo infinito para ver resultado a resultado. A frequência vai aumentado; só não aumenta mais em termos absolutos porque o número de periódicos na Hemeroteca vai diminuido; mas relativamente ao número de páginas na Hemeroteca o aumento é bastante pronunciado.

**“dar/dando/deu (um) rolé/rolê” na [Hemeroteca Digital Brasileira](http://bndigital.bn.gov.br/hemeroteca-digital/)**

```
Década                                60    70    80    90    00    10

Total de resultados                    1     8    35    27    84    29
    por milhão de páginas             0,3   2,5   14    17    50    41

Erro de reconhecimento do buscador     0     2     2     0

Sentido ‘passeio, volta’; total        1     5    28    27
    Grafia “rolé”                      1     4    16    25
    Grafia “rolê”                      0     1     8     0
    Outra/acento ilegível              0     0     4     2

Outro sentido ou sentido incerto       0     1     5     0
```

Continua a encontrar-se a expressão *dar um rolé* na linguagem de marginais, reportada em artigos sobre crimes. Entre outros:

> Depois que Queixada e Waldetar aceitaram o convite para **dar um “rolé” pela cidade**, os cinco bandidos rumaram para o conjunto Potilândia
>   [“Desvendado o crime d Pororoca”, Diário do Natal, Natal, 13 de dezembro de 1983, p. 6.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=028711_03&pesq=dar%20rol%C3%AA&pasta=ano%20198)
>
> Eles escolheram a agência bancária quando passavam pelo Alecrim, **“dando um rolé pela cidade”**, e resolveram agir, traçando os planos ali mesmo.
>   [“Assaltantes do Banorte vão hoje para a Colônia”, Diário do Natal, Natal, 20 de janeiro de 1987.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=028711_03&pesq=dando%20rol%C3%A9&pasta=ano%20198)
>
> Foram eles que chegaram para mim e disseram para irmos **dar um rolê por São Gonçalo**, a fim de arranjarmos um outro bar.
>   [“Três assassinaram mulher a golpes de chave de fenda”, *O Fluminense*, 27 de junho de 89, p. 10](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=100439_12&pesq=dar%20rol%C3%AA&pasta=ano%20198)

Mas os exemplos começam a vir maioritariamente doutros contextos, o que indica que o uso da expressão já se tinha alargado: o músico Rúben Santos “esteve dando um rolé pela Argentina” [(Luta Democrática, RJ, 1977)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=030678&pesq=rol%C3%A9%20pela%20argentina&pasta=ano%20197); “é hora de dar um rolê pelos bares, que também ninguém é de ferro” [(*Jornal da República*, São Paulo, 1979)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=194018&pesq=rol%C3%AA%20pelos%20bares&pasta=ano%20197); um taxista não quer “dar rolé desnecessário, na busca de passageiros” [(*Luta Democrática*, RJ, 1980)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=030678&pesq=rol%C3%A9%20desnecess%C3%A1rio&pasta=ano%20198).

Os vários dicionários indicam nesta aceção apenas a grafia *rolé*, exceto o [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/rol%C3%A9), que indica *rolé* e *rolê*. A grafia *rolê* tem vindo a perder peso, mas continua a aparecer. Por exemplo, “nunca ‘deu um rolê pelo fundão’ da capital” [[(Correio Brasiliense, Brasília, 2008)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=028274_05&pesq=rol%C3%AA%20pelo%20fund%C3%A3o&pasta=ano%20200) ou “dando um *rolê* por Salvador” [(Correio Brasiliense, Brasília, 2012)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=028274_06&pesq=rol%C3%AA%20por%20salvador&pasta=ano%20201).

O Jornal do Brasil (Rio de Janeiro), que começou com *rolê*, no fim dos anos 80 mudou para *rolé*, e em 1995 observa que em “São Paulo é ‘dar um rolê’” , num artigo que, apesar do aumento da frequência da expressão, sugere que esta é ainda gíria restrita de certos grupos, pois o jornalista sente necessidade de explicar o seu significado:

> PARA ENTENDER O PALAVREADO
>   […] **Dar um rolé**: dar uma volta. Em São Paulo é “dar um rolê”.
>   [*Jornal do Brasil—Programa*, Rio de Janeiro, 28-7 a 2-8-1995, p. 28.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=030015_11&pesq=paulo%20dar%20rol%C3%AA&pasta=ano%20199)

Já antes se encontrava de vez em quando essa explicação:

> “Para não bater na gente, eles mandavam quem tem cabelo encaracolado **dar um *rolé* (passeio)**”, denunciou Márcio.
>   [“Agressão e tiros para o alto”, *Jornal do Brasil*, Rio de Janeiro, 13 de outubro de 1993, p. 13.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=030015_11&pesq=rol%C3%A9%20passeio&pasta=ano%20199)
>
> Após furtarem o carro, os cinco rapazes e as mulheres ficaram alegres, afirmando que iriam **dar um “rolé” (um passeio)** pela Cidade Nova
>   [“Gang rouba e troca tiros com Polícia”, *Diário do Natal*, Natal, 29 de novembro de 1988, p. 8.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=028711_03&pesq=rol%C3%A9%20passeio&pasta=ano%20198)

Na história da expressão poderá ter tido a sua importância a canção [*Dê um rolê* (Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%AA_um_Rol%C3%AA_(can%C3%A7%C3%A3o)), lançada em 1971 pelos [Novo Baianos (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ly0JBUwL-5w), e interpretada ainda esse ano por [Gal Costa (YT)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IxziLb1EjYQ), e por [Zizi Possi (YT)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pqFXG25thk0) em 1984 [(noticiado no *Última Hora*, Rio, 1984)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=386030&pesq=trabalho%20zizi%20possi&pasta=ano%20198), e pelos [Pitty (YT) em 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SwTzvBQPSso). O que não é claro é se este “rolê” refere o movimento de capoeira ou uma volta, ou ainda se é deliberadamente ambíguo. A letra não esclarece totalmente: “enquanto eles se batem, dê um rolê”.

Com menor frequência, encontra-se *dar um rolê* noutros dois sentidos. Pode discutir-se se estes usos se inspiram na capoeira ou em ‘volta’, mas  num deles *rolê* significa ainda ‘volta’, mas no sentido ‘grande mudança’ [(Aulete 10)](http://www.aulete.com.br/volta):

> Num momento de loucura, ele [o milionário Frederico Stuart Mill] decide **dar um rolê em sua vida** e ingressar em um grupo de teatro, sem revelar a verdadeira identidade.
>   [“Cortina de vidro”, *Correio de Notícias*, Curitiba, 26-10-1989, p. 17.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=325538_01&pesq=rol%C3%A9%20sua%20vida&pasta=ano%20198)
>
> Hoje a moçada interpreta os *fifties* à sua maneira, **dando um *rolê* na moda**
>   [“A moda na trip dos fifties”, Manchete, Rio de Janeiro, 25 de setembro de 1985.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=004120&pesq=dando%20rol%C3%A9&pasta=ano%20198)
>
> Se você se enquadrar entre os [comedores] compulsivos, menos mal: eliminando os beliscos nos petiscos, aumentando a quantidade de alimentos ricos em fibras e espaçando as refeições, poderá ***dar um rolê* na compulsão**.
>   [“Quem faz a dieta de Beverly Hills pode acabar sem as células”, *Manchete*, Rio de Janeiro, 14 de maio de 1988.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=004120&pesq=rol%C3%A9%20compuls%C3%A3o&pasta=ano%20198)

O outro uso é *dar rolé (em alguém)*, que parece significar ‘zombar de, provocar’: “presidente Lula deu um rolé nos racialmente corretos” quando piropou “negona!” à ministra Benedita [(Jornal do Brasil, 2003)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=030015_12&pesq=deu%20rol%C3%AA&pasta=ano%20200); “cômico Chico Anísio dando rolê em quem tem medo de visagens” [(Jornal do Rio Branco, 1980)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=764809&pesq=dando%20rol%C3%A9&pasta=ano%20198).